# Custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not resolving

Tags: spring-boot

Hi I am new to Spring Boot (but have been using Spring in my apps for a while). I am trying to use a custom [SSM PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://gist.github.com/davidrosenstark/fa8680aa1e1f9d7e48b46269c55f6f29), based on my [SSM Client](https://gist.github.com/davidrosenstark/4a33f2c0eab59d9d7e429bd1c20aea92), that reads my properties from AWS SSM, in addition to properties in my normal application.properties. 
This code works fine in my pre-spring-boot application. However, in the new application, I see that it overrides the application.properties. And this seems to be a well documented problem.

So i decided to include the application.properties file in my custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class and load all the properties together and still it does not resolve any properties in application.properties that are marked with "${}" and resolve by my custom location. What more do i need to do?

As an alternative, I tried to have the properties i need to load from SSM to be loaded via an EnvironmentPostProcessor but it was unable to connect to the AWS SSM server at this point in the loading process (not sure why)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the EnvironmentPostProcessor. Works perfectly. See code below:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class loads SSM parameters base on region and environment
 * Needs to be added to spring.factories class so that it will be invoked. as follow:
 * org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=<full package>.SSMEnvironmentPostProcessor
 * Add the SSM propeties to other properties already set
 */

public class SSMEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private static final String QUOTE = "\"";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        SSMClient ssmClient = new SSMClient(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance(), System.getProperty("env" +
                ".region"), new ClientConfiguration());
        ssmClient.init();
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        ssmClient.getParametersByPath("/" + System.getProperty("env"), true).entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(entry -> parameters.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

        MapPropertySource mapPropertySource = new MapPropertySource("ssm", parameters);
        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(mapPropertySource);
    }




}
```